# Can cast T to comform a protocol in swift

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I want use swift generic as code show below:

```
func handle<T>(data: Data, with type: T.Type) {
    if type is B.Type {
        handleOne(data: data, with: type) //error here: In argument type 'T.Type', 'T' does not conform to expected type 'B'
        // cast T comform B?
    } else {
        handleTwo(data: data)
    }
}

func handleOne<T>(data: Data, with type: T.Type) where T:B {

}

func handleTwo(data: Data) {

}
```

...

```
protocol B {
    ...
}
```

`B` is a Protocol, Can I call `handleOne` in `handle`? Can cast `T` comform `B`?

Comment: The compiler **isn't** smart enough to know `if type is B.Type` is `true` then type is actually of type `B`. Since being of type `B` is a requirement for your `handleOne` function, then this would fail!

Comment: I don't think so, I tried in Xcode9 swift4, use `struct  A: B {}` , `handle(data: Data(), with: A.self)` , `if type is B.Type` will be `true`, you can try this

Answer (score 2):

It's not really necessary to pass in the type as a parameter as it can be retrieved from the object itself. The `is` type check operator works on instances of objects and checks against type names:

```
protocol A {}

protocol Data {}

func handle (data: Data) {
  if data is A {
    print("Handled A.")
  } else {
    print("Handled something else.")
  }
}

struct AStruct: Data, A {}

handle(data: AStruct()) // Handled A.
```

Comment: In my question, the `handleOne ` need the parameter `.Type`.

Comment: This should work: `func handle<T: Data>(data: T) {
  if data is A {
    handleOne(data: data, with: type(of: data))
  } else {
    print("Handled something else.")
  }
}`

Comment: You could also use T.self instead of type(of: data).